# Laravel MIN MAX GroupBy from Collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections, aggregate-functions, query-builder

I have single query then I loop using forEach.

I filter by eliminated null value then pushed into a collection

And then I flattened to convert 2D array ti 1D array.

So, I have data in collection format.

My question is how to get MIN MAX from collection?

For example my data:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#193
  #items: array:8 [
    0 => {#388
      +"id": 498
      +"id_user": "20021635"
      +"name": "Jeany"
      +"department": "IAD"
      +"location": "Rose Tower – 1st Floor"
      +"updated_at": "2021-03-18 10:12:15"
    }
    1 => {#379
      +"id": 498
      +"id_user": "20021635"
      +"name": "Jeany"
      +"department": "IAD"
      +"location": "Rose Tower – 1st Floor"
      +"updated_at": "2021-03-18 10:25:16"
    }
    2 => {#394
      +"id": 498
      +"id_user": "20021635"
      +"name": "Jeany"
      +"department": "IAD"
      +"location": "Rose Tower – 1st Floor"
      +"updated_at": "2021-03-18 10:29:16"
    }
    3 => {#395
      +"id": 498
      +"id_user": "20021635"
      +"name": "Jeany"
      +"department": "IAD"
      +"location": "Rose Tower – 1st Floor"
      +"updated_at": "2021-03-18 10:05:15"
    }
    4 => {#389
      +"id": 470
      +"id_user": "10025488"
      +"name": "Michael Angelo"
      +"department": "HR"
      +"location": "Rose Tower – 1st Floor"
      +"updated_at": "2021-03-18 10:07:15"
    }
    5 => {#397
      +"id": 470
      +"id_user": "10025488"
      +"name": "Michael Angelo"
      +"department": "HR"
      +"location": "Rose Tower – 1st Floor"
      +"updated_at": "2021-03-18 10:09:15"
    }
    6 => {#401
      +"id": 470
      +"id_user": "10025488"
      +"name": "Michael Angelo"
      +"department": "HR"
      +"location": "Rose Tower – 1st Floor"
      +"updated_at": "2021-03-18 10:12:15"
    }
    7 => {#402
      +"id": 470
      +"id_user": "10025488"
      +"name": "Michael Angelo"
      +"department": "Rose Tower"
      +"location": "Rose Tower – 1st Floor"
      +"updated_at": "2021-03-18 10:14:15"
    }
  ]
}
```

expected output:

```
 +"id": 498
      +"id_user": "20021635"
      +"name": "Jeany"
      +"department": "IAD"
      +"location": "Rose Tower – 1st Floor"
      +"time_in": "2021-03-18 10:05:15"
      +"time_out": "2021-03-18 10:29:16"
+"id": 470
      +"id_user": "10025488"
      +"name": "Michael Angelo"
      +"department": "HR"
      +"location": "Rose Tower – 1st Floor"
      +"time_in": "2021-03-18 10:07:15"
      +"time_out": "2021-03-18 10:14:15"
```

Code:

```
$person = collect([]);
    foreach ($machine_list as $key => $value){
        $contactBy = DB::tamachine('attendance')
        ->select(DB::raw('user.id as id,
                          user.idemployee as id_user,
                          user.name as name,
                          user.id_dept as department,
                          machine.loc_name as location,
                          attendance.updated_at'))
        
        ->Join('user','attendance.id_user','=','user.id')
        ->Join('machine','attendance.id_machine','=','machine.id_machine')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($value){
            $query->where('attendance.id_machine', $value->id_machine)
                  ->orWhere('attendance.id_machine2', $value->id_machine2)
                  ->orWhere('attendance.id_machine3', $value->id_machine3);
        })
        ->where('attendance.id_user','<>',$id_user)
        ->whereBetween('attendance.updated_at', [Carbon::parse($minmax_person[0]->timestart,'GMT'), Carbon::parse($minmax_person[0]->timeend,'GMT')])
        // ->groupBy('user.id','user.idemployee','user.name','user.id_dept','machine.loc_name')
        ->get();
    
        if(!$contactBy->isEmpty()){
            $person->push($contactBy);
        }
    }
$person->flatten();
```

any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Show how you got to this script, not just explain it. That way one can derive  the tools you are using.

Comment: done @AntonyMN.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods) Methods

Create an empty collection object then use min and max method on existing collection object and push it's value in empty collection object using push method

[Max](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-max)

[Min](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-min)

[Push](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-push)